# Can SQL with CASE condition use index in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

When I write a SQL like 
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.col && object`, I could use the index I built (as it support && operator), but with

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
    CASE 
    WHEN table.col && object = true THEN true 
    ELSE false 
    END
```

It seems I can't use the index?

What is the reason of this? Is there any way to solve it?
Actually I want to implement a logic like `CASE WHEN a&&b = true THEN a<b ELSE a>b END` with the support of index, is that possible?

Comment: Please give an example of a `CASE WHEN test THEN true ELSE false END` that couldn't be rewritten as a normal `WHERE test`

Comment: What are these a and b anyway? Arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that there is not situation where a `case` expression would use an index in Postgres.  This is because the `case` expression enforces an order of evaluation -- which is quite hard to ensure once indexes are involved.

There might be some exceptions where the compiler recognizes that the `case` expression is redundant and it gets removed before the optimization phase.

That said, your case expression is useless.  Just use:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE table.col AND object ;
```

Notes:

- The SQL Standard for boolean and is `AND`.  Use it.
- `= true` is redundant.  You can include it, but it is not necessary.
- You have two boolean columns.  In many cases, an index will not be used even if available because the columns are (probably) not very selective.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to even use a `CASE` expression here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE (some_condition AND a < b) OR (!some_condition AND a > b);
```

That being said, I am surprised that an index cannot be used, because in general your logic can probably be optimized to something like the above, without needing a `CASE` expression.

Comment: I'm not surprised an index isn't used *when a CASE is put in the where clause*

Comment: I wrote assuming the optimizer is smart enough to rephrase it as I have done above.  If not, then maybe I agree with you.

Answer (score -1):

Your query is not so much clear.But as per assumption,you can do something like this

SELECT 
CASE WHEN table.col && object = true THEN true ELSE false END as  
INTO #TEMP_TABLE
FROM table

Then you can create a CLUSTERED/NON_CLUSTERED INDEX

CREATE INDEX idx_col on TABLE #TEMP_TABLE()

Then you can select the result:

SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TABLE WHERE  =

Comment: Why `CASE WHEN a&&b = true THEN true ELSE false END` - why not just `a&&b`

Comment: in else it is not mandatory that user will always check "false"

Comment: Not my downvote, but I still didn't understand how you reason that a&&b resulting in a boolean, is compared to another boolean, resulting in a boolean that is then tested and if true then yet another boolean is returned.. it's just a&&b! If we're loving the booleans how about `CASE WHEN (a&&b = true AND b&&a = true) = true THEN (a&&b = true) = true ELSE (b&&a = true) <> false END` ? :)